# Hive multiple subqueries in WHERE predicate workaround

Tags: sql, hadoop, select, hive, subquery

I have three tables and I would like to query `table3` using conditions based on `table1` and `table2`. Here is the simplified version of the data and queries:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id int
);

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(3);

+------------+--+
| table1.id  |
+------------+--+
| 1          |
| 2          |
| 3          |
+------------+--+

CREATE TABLE table2 (
  code varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO table2 VALUES('a');
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES('b');
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES('c');

+--------------+--+
| table2.code  |
+--------------+--+
| a            |
| b            |
| c            |
+--------------+--+

CREATE TABLE table3 (
  id int,
  code varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO table3 VALUES(1,'d');
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES(1,'a');
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES(2,'b');
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES(2,'e');
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES(4,'a');
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES(4,'d');

+------------+--------------+--+
| table3.id  | table3.code  |
+------------+--------------+--+
| 1          | d            |
| 1          | a            |
| 2          | b            |
| 2          | e            |
| 4          | a            |
| 4          | d            |
+------------+--------------+--+
```

Basically, I like to get the records from `table3` only if `id` exists in `table1` and `code` not exists in `table2`. So the result should be just

```
1,d
2,e
```

This below query doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE (table3.id IN (SELECT table1.id FROM
table1)) AND NOT (table3.code IN (SELECT table2.code FROM table2));
```

I got this error:

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException
>   [Error 10249]: Line 1:94 Unsupported SubQuery Expression 'code': Only
>   1 SubQuery expression is supported. (state=42000,code=10249)

Independently, each condition works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE (table3.id IN (SELECT table1.id FROM table1));

+------------+--------------+--+
| table3.id  | table3.code  |
+------------+--------------+--+
| 1          | d            |
| 1          | a            |
| 2          | b            |
| 2          | e            |
+------------+--------------+--+

SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE NOT (table3.code IN (SELECT table2.code FROM table2));

+------------+--------------+--+
| table3.id  | table3.code  |
+------------+--------------+--+
| 1          | d            |
| 2          | e            |
| 4          | d            |
+------------+--------------+--+
```

**IMPORTANT**: I cannot do `JOIN` or modify anything in `FROM` as this is a part of a reporting system so the only thing I can do is to tweak WHERE clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rewrite it using `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t3.*
FROM table3 t3
JOIN table1 t1
  ON t3.id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
  ON t2.code = t3.code
WHERE t2.code IS NULL;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c5607a637c146d0d01165f8761c326b3)**

---

> *the only thing I can do is to tweak WHERE clause.*

```
SELECT *
FROM Table3 t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM table3 t3
              JOIN table1 t1
                ON t3.id = t1.id
              LEFT JOIN table2 t2
                ON t2.code = t3.code
             WHERE t2.code IS NULL
               AND t3.id = t.id
               AND t3.code = t.code)
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6be42f82cc3dc912590608a563732f7d)**

Comment: Your second example works but I am still trying to understand how it did it... Mind to give a few explanations?

Comment: @HP. Sure. As you can see second example subquery is exactly as the first. I replaced IN/NOT IN with `JOIN and LEFT JOIN` accordingly. Then you said that you cannot use `JOIN` but you could manipulate only WHERE condition. So I use EXISTS clause and correlated subquery.

Answer (score 1):

One dirty trick you can use is to cross join `table1` and `table2`, since you don't care about their relationship anyway, and use an `exists` condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table3 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT     *
                   FROM       table1
                   CROSS JOIN table2
                   WHERE      table3.id = table1.id ON table3.code = table2.code)
```

**EDIT:**

While the above query should work, its performance probably won't be great. A slightly faster variant would be to use `union all` in the subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table3 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT     *
                   FROM       table1
                   WHERE      table3.id = table1.id 
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT     *
                   FROM       table2
                   WHERE      table3.code = table2.code)
```

Comment: I got this error: Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Line 4:11 Invalid SubQuery expression 'TOK_ALLCOLREF' in definition of SubQuery sq_1 [
EXISTS (SELECT     *
FROM       table1
WHERE      table3.id = table1.id
UNION ALL
SELECT     *
FROM       table2
WHERE      table3.code = table2.code)
] used as sq_1 at Line 3:11: For Exists/Not Exists operator SubQuery must be Correlated. (state=42000,code=40000)

Comment: The first example got error: `Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 6:33 cannot recognize input near 'ON' 'table3' '.' in expression specification (state=42000,code=40000)`

Answer (score 0):

`NOT IN` is a simpler way to write your query:

```
SELECT t3.*
FROM table3 t3
WHERE t3.id IN (SELECT table1.id FROM table1) AND
      t3.code NOT IN (SELECT table2.code FROM table2);
```

If you are limited to one subquery, this gets tricky.  Here is one possibility, although I'm not sure if hive will accept it:

```
where exists (select 1
              from table1 t1
              where t1.id = t3.id and
                    not exists (select 1
                                from table2 t2
                                where t2.code = t3.code
                               )
             )
```

You can do this without the double nesting:

```
where exists (select 1
              from table1 t1 left join
                   table2 t2
                   on t2.code = t3.code
              where t1.id = t3.id
             )
```

Comment: I got this error for both `used as sq_1 at Line 1:27: For Exists/Not Exists operator SubQuery must be Correlated. (state=42000,code=40000)`

Comment: @HP. . . .  All the subqueries are correlated.  That is an odd message.